# Is it a bad idea to hack the i18n system to generate <p> tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, copy, translation

A lot of my copy has paragraphs. It would be cumbersome to wrap each paragraph in its own `i18n.translate` invocation. Is it a bad idea to modify the i18n system in rails so that it generates these and wraps them in `<p>` tags? I guess the hard part is determining when to generate them and when not to.

Are there any known solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very very bad idea. Do not mix translations with view code. Really, don't do it.

Comment: `.introtext.secondparagraph`…

Comment: I don't really understand the comments :P A translation is a translation, a model is a model, a controller is a controller. There is a reason why logic is not inside views, there is a reason why formatting should not be inside i18n.

Comment: Alright. Well the key distinction here is between copy and translation. Someone writing copy for a part of a page can decide that it should have 3 paragraphs instead of 2. With this system, they cannot make that decision without informing the coder.

Comment: (so the separation between content and coding is broken)

Comment: I don't see where the template messes with the translation in your example. The person who is translating does not(and should not) have any authority on the structure of the webpage. The programmer or designer is the one that creates the structure through views. The translator just gets a string and returns a translation, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Right but in my use case it's a copyrighter, not a translator. I suppose I should make my own micro-cms meta system a layer about i18n.